# Android Drawing on Multiple Canvas Multiple Activities

Tags: java, android, android-activity, android-canvas

Here is my problem:

I currently have on Canvas in my main game activity that is constantly being drawn with OnDraw().  This is a board game with two players.  When a player's turn begins, there are many options that the player can do, and I would like all of this to be put in a different class.

Also, this new class must draw NEW animations on top of the current canvas.  These animations will came from attacks (I haven't even looked into animations yet).  So basically I would like another canvas on top of the main one.

Furthermore, the OnDraw function in the main activity must PAUSE and wait for the other class with the canvas on top to complete.

Let me try and summarize this: I have a main game class with one canvas.  This class handles the players' turns and setting up the game.  It also draws the playing field.  I need another class, when it is a player's turn, to draw animations and other things on top of the current canvas.

Can anybody help me with this?

NOTE : I looked into Fragments and FragmentManager, but it seems I can only use XML Views with that and not RenderViews.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You might want to consider using multiple bitmaps as buffers and then just add them on top of each other before rendering to the canvas.
There is a nice example in the "samples" pack that comes with the sdk that shows of how you can merge bitmaps on top of each other.
Let me know if you want to try this out and need some more pointers on how to do it :)

Comment: I already have multiple bitmaps drawing on top of each other on the first canvas.  The thing is, that OnDraw() function needs to stop, while animations or other drawings need to be drawn from a different function.  When the animations or other drawings are finished, it continues the initial OnDraw() function.  Does that make sense?

Comment: Could you not just run the same draw loop al the time, and select what bitmap you want to do thing to depending on the game state. So if noting changed on the game canvas except a explosion animation, you could have the explosion on a separate bitmap and merge it with the "background" after rendering the next frame of the explosion. I assume that you want to avoid rendering everything for every frame, and then just dividing the canvas into as many bitmaps as you might need and render whatever changes to the individually bitmaps and then merging should do the trick, or am I missing the point?